# Получить итератор на i-ый элемент строки

Tags: c++

Получить итератор на центральный элемент строки, не используя метод инкремента итератора на начало, то есть без:

```
auto iter=tempStr.begin();
while(*iter!=centerSymb) ++iter;
```

Comment: Можно зайти с противоположной стороны и декрементить итератор конца строки.

Comment: Рандомному итератору можно прибавлять число, а не только инкрементировать. Поэтому получить итератор на i-ый элемент можно так `auto iter = tempStr.begin() + i;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Похоже отвечать придется сразу на 3 вопроса. Потому что ваш заголовок, тело вопроса и код в примере говорят о 3 разных вещах.

---

**Звголовок: Получить итератор на i-ый элемент строки**

Наиболее универсальный способ:

```
auto it = std::next(str.begin(), i);
```

Для итераторов произволного доступа это эквивалентно `str.begin() + i`, для остальных `for(std::ptrdiff_t pos = 0; pos < i; ++pos) ++it;`.

---

**Вопрос: Получить итератор на центральный элемент строки**

```
auto it = std::next(str.begin(), str.size() / 2);
```

---

**Код: Получить итератoр на некоторый символ**

```
auto it = std::find(str.begin(), str.end(), symbol);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
auto Iter = tempStr.begin() + tempStr.find(centerSymb);
```